# What should the criteria be for questions asking for a quote from an Arabic text?

Tags: discussion, questions

Should questions asking for Arabic quotes, like [this one](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7473/i-need-an-arabic-quote-from-fath-al-bari) be on-topic here?  the previously linked question, to me looks non-constructive to me, because one can go straight to Fathul Bari and get an Arabic quote, in other words it is easily accessible.  But let's say there is a similar question, asking for a quote of a book, which it's origin is in Arabic, but the Arabic text is not easily accessible, would this question be on-topic?  Basically my question would be what should the criteria for questions asking for quotes from an Arabic text?

Comment: I figure "too localized" is appropriate here, because it's highly unlikely that someone else would come here looking for the exact same thing. Ask them to go to chat instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think questions like this are fine, as long as they are made just a little bit more useful. For example, the question you linked to could turn into something like: "What did ibn Hajr say about such-and-such hadith"? These books are not always easily accessible to everyone - _especially non-Arabic speakers - people may not be well-versed in looking them up and navigating through them.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for an original Arabic reference seems, to me, to be the very *definition* of [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification); translations are at best interpretations, and it is not uncommon for meaning (or ambiguity) to be lost therefrom.

I feel the linked question is clear, answerable and fundamentally on-topic.  There doesn't appear to be any reason to *close* it (much less delete it).  An argument can be made for "too localized," but I myself have often sought original sources of something I've seen referenced in an English-language essay or fatwa; when the most readily-available search criteria is the particular (and often peculiar) translation used in the article itself, I would find a question like this coming up on my first search to be immensely valuable.

It does, however, still risk attracting downvotes only because of "no research effort": The exact *book and page number* are clearly present *in the question itself*.  Unless the poster provides a reason to believe that they're not accurate, or that he's already attempted (and failed) to find the information using the specified reference, it just looks like he's not even trying.  Nobody wants a Q&A site full of make-work.